# Variable written in parentheses at end of expression

Tags: python

I'm going through a CNTK tutorial, and I have the following function:

```
def create_model(features):
with C.layers.default_options(init=C.layers.glorot_uniform(),
                              activation=C.ops.relu):
    h = features
    for _ in range(num_hidden_layers):
        h = C.layers.Dense(hidden_layers_dim)(h)
    r = C.layers.Dense(num_output_classes, activation=None)(h)
    return r
```

The function itself is not my point of confusion, I'm actually concerned with the syntax on the last two lines before the `return` statement: `h = C.layers.Dense(hidden_layers_dim)(h)` and `r = C.layers.Dense(num_output_classes, activation=None)(h)`.

What is this `(h)` that's being written at the end of the line?  What is this syntax called and what does it do?  I have tried to look it up but I don't even know what to call it in searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C.layers.Dense(hidden_layers_dim)` returns a function which is being called with the argument `h`. You could also write it as:

```
fun = C.layers.Dense(hidden_layers_dim)
h = fun(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was said it returns a function, so let's say you have:

```
def hello(name):
    print "Hello, {}!".format(name)

def hi(name):
    print "Hi, {}!".format(name)

def greeting_selection(number):
    if number == 1:
        return hello  # note that this is the function above
    else:
        return hi     # this also... the functions hi above...
```

Having that you can do!

```
greeting_selection(1)("Jeff Davis")
#output: Hello, Jeff Davis

greeting_selection(2)("Jeff Davis")
#output: Hi, Jeff Davis
```

Hope it helps! :D